# React - how to implement a page-wide manipulation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to implement a page-wide dictionary (for every page in the site), so that when a word that appears in the dictionary is hovered than a small box appears next to it with a definition.

one way to do it is to wrap every text in the site with a component that loops over the text and adds the required effects.

How-ever with jQuery I could do it with much less work by a page-wide action that loops over all text in the page.

1. Is there a coorect way to implement a page-wide action in React?
2. Is it possible (i.e. recommended) to mix react and jQuery

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rough outline of a reactive way to do that:

1. Have top level component `Dictionary` that renders a [`Provider`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) exposing a function that allows other components consuming the context to look up a word in the dictionary.
2. Create a component `Explanation` that consumes the context provided by `Dictionary` and checks for the existence of a description for the word and if it exists renders a popover on hover.

Example:

```
const tokenize = (text, dictionary) => {
    return text
        .split(/(\b\w+\b)/gi)
        .map(word => {
            const description = dictionary[word];

            if (!description) return word;

            return (
                <span title={description} className="dashed">
                    {word}
                </span>
            );
        })
        .reduce((acc, current, idx) => {
            if (typeof acc[acc.length - 1] === 'string' && typeof current === 'string') {
                acc[acc.length - 1] += current;
                return acc;
            }

            acc.push(current);
            return acc;
        }, []);
};

const DictionaryContext = createContext({getDescription: () => null});

// holds the words and exposed function to look a word up
const Dictionary = ({words, children}) => {
    const getTokens = useCallback(text => tokenize(text, words), [words]);
    return <DictionaryContext.Provider value={{getTokens}}>{children}</DictionaryContext.Provider>;
};

// gets the explanation from the context and renders it as a title
const Explanation = ({children}) => {
    const {getTokens} = useContext(DictionaryContext);
    if (!children) return null;
    return getTokens(children);
};
```

Live Example:

[image: Edit 0xvj2o2k4n]

But still you would need to wrap the whole text into a component that does so. This is due to how react works. It is declarative in that is describes every possible way to display the data at compile-time. But actually I find that to be the better design as you should explicitly mark text as potentially having explanations.

> Is it possible (i.e. recommended) to mix react and jQuery

It is possible but as the concepts are fundamentally different I would try to avoid that. React keeps an internal representation of the DOM and if it is manipulated from outside by e.g. jQuery it can yield unexpected results that are ugly to work around. React ans jQuery are definitely not a good fit.

EDIT:

This is a more robust version (thanks @Elia Weiss) of the same code, it supports:

1. Unicode
2. Multiple word phrases
3. Handle non text objects

[image: Edit n3qz2r80lj]